# Check if the shortcode is executed or not

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I use Elementor page builder in WordPress, I made a section on the single store page and put the WooCommerce message display shortcode in it. WooCommerce messages are displayed correctly, I want to condition for the section, if it doesn't show a message, don't show the section. Because I don't want the extra section to be empty in the html codes when a message doesn't show and not to make the site heavy. How to condition that if it displays a message, it will show the section. I also use the [Dynamic Content for Elementor](https://www.dynamic.ooo/) plugin for condition. Do you have any ideas?

[image]
[image]

**Update :**

I found that using the following code, all the messages running in WooCommerce can be displayed :

```
$notices  = WC()->session->get( 'wc_notices', array() );
```

Is it possible to make a condition in Elementor or [Dynamic Content for Elementor](https://www.dynamic.ooo/) plugin that if the `$notices` variable does not have a value, it will not show the section at all?

I came across the following code which apparently hides a section by putting it in the functions.php file :

```
function c_cccc( $bool, $element ) {
    $settings = $element->get_settings();
    if( 'test' === $settings['_element_id'] ){
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
} add_filter( 'elementor/frontend/widget/should_render', 'c_cccc', 10, 3 );
```

What should I put instead of the text? This is the html code :

```
<section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-adf8a43 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="adf8a43" data-element_type="section">
    <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
        <div class="elementor-row">
            <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-8ef971a" data-id="8ef971a" data-element_type="column">
                <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-e64f93a elementor-widget elementor-widget-shortcode" data-id="e64f93a" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="shortcode.default">
                            <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                                <div class="elementor-shortcode">
                                    <div class="woocommerce">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```