# Section conditioning not working in Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Please go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76098576/check-if-the-shortcode-is-executed-or-not) first.

I found that it is possible to condition the Elementor section. Using the following code, the section will be hidden, but I want to give it more conditions

```
function c_cccc( $bool, $element ) {
    $settings = $element->get_settings();
    if( 'id_section' === $settings['_element_id'] ){
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'elementor/frontend/section/should_render', 'c_cccc', 10, 3 );
```

I want the section to show when there is a WooCommerce notice. But it doesn't work!

```
function c_cccc( $bool, $element ) {
    $notices  = WC()->session->get( 'wc_notices', array() );
    $settings = $element->get_settings();
    if( 'id_section' === $settings['_element_id'] && count ( $notices ) == 0 ){
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'elementor/frontend/section/should_render', 'c_cccc', 10, 3 );
```

**Where is the problem with my work?**